# Does zmq need integrity checks in application layer?

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system

I'm building a distributed application using ZMQ framework that needs to assure the integrity of the packages exchanged. My question is whether or not do I need to perform integrity checks on the client and server on the application layer.

I have implemented a checksum approach using MD5 hash in both client's and server's side. However, I suspect that this might be redundant since zmq might be already handling integrity checks in the background. I have read [ZMQ - The guide](https://zguide.zeromq.org/) and found scarce information on this matter rather than small references that indicate that zmq already does integrity checks:

> It delivers whole messages exactly as they were sent, using a simple
> framing on the wire. If you write a 10k message, you will receive a
> 10k message.

I also searched in forums, including SO and couldn't found any solid reference that could confirm the reference. I would appreciate if someone could confirm it and ideally include a useful source.

**EDIT**

---

I am looking for answers other than "trust the docs" or "implement checksums" for two reasons:

- I think that there need to be clear and easy-to-find references to what seems to be one of the key selling points of ZMQ.
- The system under design must be fast, thus not wasting time in redundant ops.

Comment: Packet loss should be handled by the underlying TCP connection, but it's never wrong to double-check your data to see if it's what you expect. Just add a simple MD5 at the end of the message and check if your payload matches. If not, request a new message

Comment: I am familiar with TCP and its sequence numbers to keep track of the segments. However, my question is whether ZMQ has additional integrity checks on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it depends on what you're worried about most.

ZMQ is built on top of tcp and other protocols, and these in turn rely on underlying things like IP, Ethernet. When you start getting down towards these physical layers of a network stack, there's integrity checking built in to provide reliable services to the layers above (include application libraries like ZMQ). So, in ordinary circumstances, one would not need to put in your own integrity checks because that's already taken care of for you. ZMQ does not do anything extra so far as I know - it simply assumes the underlying network stack always delivers bytes properly, intact.

However, such underlying integrity checks do not guarantee to eliminate all bit errors, they just get the bit error rate up to some very good level where most applications don't care (e.g. 1 in 10^12) and probably never, ever experience a problem. Adding in a supplementary checksum is going to push the net b.e.r. to even more very safe levels.

If you're worried about some active attack by a malicious third party against the zmtp protocol itself, then you may wish to introduce your own integrity check, likely cryptographic in nature, with all that entails. This might involve using libsodium along with ZeroMQ. That certainly was a thing, and probably still is unless I'm out of date and have missed a deprecation notice.

**Summary**

I'd say:

- Ordinary app, runtime of days, weeks - nothing extra needed
- Very long running app (years) and bit errors are utterly unacceptable (e.g. a safety critical application) - add a checksum
- Needs to operate in a hostile environment where protocol attacks may occur - add a strong encryption layer like libsodium.

Comment: hey bazza, thanks for taking time answering this question. The point of the question is to clarify the comments that appear in the guide which suggest that zmq is doing some extra work verifying message delivery and integrity. Your comment suggests that there is no additional check, however, the docs suggest the oppsite.

Comment: @IgnacioA no worries. I think that part of the docs is to do with ZMQ being message orientated, not stream orientated. If you send 3 messages, "abc", then "def", and "ghi", it's ensuring that they're not going to get mixed up and delivered as "ab", "cde", "fghi". Note that a stream connection would deliver "abcdefghi". In the source code for ZMQ, when reading data from a file descriptor to make the message, it's simply called `read()` into some temporary buffer, followed by a `memcpy()` into the message buffer; no processing is performed on the message content itself (not that I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter1/) i read it as the entire **purpose** of ZeroMO is reliable transmission.

Comment: As stated in the question I know that there are already vague references that suggest reliability, but what I am looking for is to confirm this via paper/articles or better confirmation than blindly trusting these comments.

Answer (score 0):

The ZeroMQ (ZMQ) messaging library does not require integrity checks in the application layer. ZMQ provides a set of low-level communication protocols that enable applications to exchange messages with each other in a fast and efficient manner. ZMQ does not include any built-in mechanisms for integrity checks, such as error correction or checksum calculations, at the application layer.

However, this does not mean that applications built on top of ZMQ do not need integrity checks. Depending on the specific requirements and goals of the application, it may be necessary to implement integrity checks in the application layer to ensure the correctness and reliability of the data being exchanged. For example, an application may want to include checksum calculations or error correction mechanisms in order to detect and correct errors in the transmitted data.

In general, the decision to include integrity checks in an application built on top of ZMQ will depend on the specific requirements and goals of the application, as well as the trade-offs between performance, reliability, and complexity. It is up to the developers of the application to determine whether integrity checks are necessary, and to implement appropriate mechanisms to ensure the integrity of the data being exchanged.